# Python3 http.sever invalid syntax

Tags: python, python-3.x, simplehttpserver

[image: A Screenshot of the result]

Hello everyone!
I am trying to get a basic python server running. But unfortunately it doesn't work and after hours of googling I have simply no clue.

I installed Python3, checked the version and differed the syntax, but it's no use: It always gives me an "invalid syntax" error.
Anyone who knows what's going wrong?

thanks in advance !

Comment: Please do _not_ paste screenshots in your questions. Paste the actual text messages.

Comment: This question is surely a dupe.

Comment: The linked question isn't an exact duplicate, but it's essentially the same problem: trying to run something inside the Python interactive interpreter that actually needs to be run in the OS command prompt.

Comment: Please see [Why may I not upload images of code on SO when asking a question?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to use that command on the command line:

i.e.

```
C:\Users\Marc>python -m http.server
```

this command calls the Windows equivalent directory of the Unix: `/usr/lib/python3.x/http/server.py`. So something like: `C:\Python3x\Lib\http\server.py`.

Comment: I seriously don't know why it didn't work in the first place, but thank you very much!

Comment: @MarcSzy You were trying to run that system command in the Python interpreter... You can tell by the three greater than signs at the prompt (`>>>`). Please accept (grey --> green arrow next to this answer) since it fixed!